# Java locks with synchronized keyword

Tags: java, synchronize

I saw this in a tutorial, they asked if there is a problem with the following code. To me it looked like b() cannot be accessed as a() is already having the control over the monitor. Am I right in thinking so?

```
public class Test {
    public synchronized void a() {
        b();
        System.out.println("I am at a");
    }
    public synchronized void b() {
        System.out.println("I am at b");
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone voted this down with no explanation?

I don't know the answer either, care to explain??

Comment: I don't know the reason for the downvote, but it seems that the OP didn't just try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no problem with that code. 
Note two things:

1. `synchronized SomeType foo() { ... }` is equivalent to

   ```
   SomeType foo() {
       synchronized (this) { ... } 
   }
   ```

   It locks the `this` instance of the enclosing class. So, in your case `a()` and `b()` are locking the same thing
2. If a thread is already holding a lock on some object's monitor, it prevents another thread from acquiring a lock on the same object, but the same thread can acquire more locks if it needs too, that is not affected. So

   ```
   public synchronized void a() {  // acquires lock on this
      b();                         // also aquires lock on this, but it's ok because it is the same thread
      System.out.println("I am at a");
   }
   ```

   While a thread is inside `a()`, no other thread will be able to call either `a()` or `b()` on the same instance. If they try to, they will have to wait until the current thread exits `a()`. But the current thread itself is not affected, it can call any synchronized method on this object, because it is already holding the lock.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're incorrect. The *thread* has control of the monitor, not the method, and so it's capable of following execution into as many methods synchronized on the same object as needed.